# Play 2.4, error: package play.* does not exist

Tags: java, playframework

I wanted to start a bit using the play framework (2.4.4) and wanted to follow a tutorial. I was following [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLrmnjPQsZc) from their site, using the play-java template and importing it to IntelliJ 15, but after starting the server and checking the project out in the browser, I get the error:

> error: package play.* does not exist

I also tried to just download the finished introduction project [here](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-java-intro) and test it, but I stil get the similiar error:

> error: package play.mvc does not exist

Am I missing something (plugin, package or so) that I forgot to include/install/update? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scala plugin helped me here rather than installing only play 2.x plugin

Answer (score 0):

You should install Play 2.0 Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA.

From IDEA: File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories -> find Play 2.0 Support.

More about plugin at: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7080?pr=

More info at: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html

Comment: I actually already have the Scala plugin, which now includes the Play 2.0 Support plugin.

Comment: I confirm this, using Scala plugin, version 2.2.0 happens to include "Scala, SBT, SSP, HOCON and Play 2 support."